# Find the maximum of $x$ satisfies the cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $a,b,c,d$ be integers with $1\leq a,b,c,d\leq10$, and $x$ be real such that

$ax^3-bx^2-cx-d=0$. How to find the maximum of $x$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any try from you??

Comment: Let $t,u,v$ be roots of $x^3-\frac{b}{a}x^2-\frac{c}{a}x-\frac{d}{a}=0$ . Then $tuv = \frac{d}{a}$, $tu+tv+uv=-\frac{c}{a}$, and $t+u+v=\frac{b}{a}$.  Now we have to find maximum of $t$ . I can't go from here.

Answer (score 1):

From Descartes' rule of signs, it is evident the cubic $f(x) = ax^3-bx^2-cx-d$ has exactly one positive root for all allowable $a, b, c, d$, so we just need to find its maximum value.

Let $r$ be the positive root of $p(r)=r^3-10(r^2+r+1)$. It is clear $p(x)> 0$ for $x> r$, as $r$ is the only one positive root, where the sign turns from negative to positive.

Now if $x>r$, we have $f(x)\ge p(x)>p(r)=0$.  Thus $f(x)$ cannot have any root $> r$.

Numerically $r \approx 10.993$, but if an exact formula is needed, you need to use a method like Cardano's formula to get $r = \frac13 \left(10+\sqrt[3]{5 (317+3 \sqrt{1401})}+\sqrt[3]{5(317-3 \sqrt{1401})}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is to find the largest zero of above polynomial. The estimate can be found, when coefficients are not known, by using  [zero bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#cite_note-Fujiwara1916-4) for polynomials. For example if we use Cauchy's zero bound for the location of the zeros of a polynomial, we shall get $|x|\leq 1+\frac{1}{a}\max\left\{b,c,d\right\}\leq 11.$

Answer (score -1):

discriminant of this equation is 
$c^2b^2-4(db^3+c^3a)+18abcd-27d^2b^2$ thus when the  discriminant will have max value that equation will have max value for $x$.or use vieta's formula